# Creating a histogram of the characters in an array with a method

Tags: java, arrays, counting

```
public static int [] letterCount (String str) {
  int letterCounts [] = new int [26];
  // Initalize counter array //
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  // All lowercase to avoid error //
  char abc [] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
  // Initalize abc array to compare with char from string //
for (int index : str.toCharArray()) {
// Converts str to char array and index takes values //
  for (char letter : abc) {
  // Goes through letters of alphabet for comparison //
    if (index == letter){
    // If index equals to the letter of alphabet cycled on add that value to the corresponding element in counter array //
    letterCounts[index]++;
    }  
  } 
}
  return letterCounts;
 }
```

This is what I have so far the error message I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 97 out of bounds for length 26
    at Histogram.letterCount(Histogram.java:15)
```

The string I input was "az".

I have tried changing the sizes of my arrays, that did nothing the same error message appeared. I had a different method of doing this before but it only counted each character as 1 and it was not in its corresponding element it should be. Here is the code for that one, the formatting is terrible

```
public void IndexOfString(String s){
    char letter;
  int [] counts = new int [26];
  char [] abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz".toCharArray();
  char [] sArray = s.toCharArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    for (int j : abc){
    letter = s.charAt(i);
    if (letter == j){
    counts[i]++;
    }
    }  
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
System.out.println(counts[i]);
}
Input = "aa"  
Output:
1
1
0
0
0
0
...
```

I have tried using a switch with the alphabet and I still get the same error message so it has to be something wrong with my arrays. Thanks for any help

Comment: you do not need extra array `abc` at all, just subtract `a` from letter, i.e.: `counts[letter - 'a']++;`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thank you, this was shown during the lesson and I had no clue about Unicode (that was not explained at all yet and I am very novice). But thank you it now works perfectly

Comment: Please post a minimal _reproducible_ example. Currently, it's not clear how `letterCount` and `IndexOfString` methods use each other.